# Unexpected behaviour on top attribute inside bootstrap card-group

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have unexpected behavior inside a bootstrap card group.

Here is what I got:

[image: bootstrap column issue with image]

As you can see, the third card image haven't the same top value than other ones.
But all these cards have the same html and CSS code (no JS except bootstrap one in this page).

**What I tried:**

- Delete this third card and I saw then the second card (the shoe image) have this top attribute problem. So it's not a problem of card but a problem of container which is a bootstrap card-deck.

Result:

[image]

- Verify computed style (inspect -> style -> computed) of this image, which told me that the `top: 50%` and `position: relative` of the image are computed. The image don't move if i change the top value.

**If you need, here is my code:**

**code**

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 9px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card img {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  transition: top 0.8s ease;
}

.card:hover img {
  top: 15%;
  -ms-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: top 0.8s ease;
  transition: top 0.8s ease;
}

.card img.rotated {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(20deg);
  -ms-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
}

.card:hover img.rotated {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
  transition: transform 0.8s ease, top 0.8s ease;
}


/** Dark-blue background **/
.card:before {
    background: #2b3b44;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: circle(450px at 50% 50%);

    -ms-transition: 0.8s ease;
    -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.8s ease;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.card:hover:before {
    clip-path: circle(70px at 80% 10%);
}


/** Card text **/

.card-title {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 17px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.card:hover {
  color: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

  <!-- stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css" type="text/css">

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- body -->
  <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
    <div class="row my-3">

      <!-- cards container -->
      <div class="card-deck">

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img alt="Outdoor" height="128px" width="128px" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/backpack/backpack_PNG6323.png" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Outdoor</h5>
            <p>first line</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img class="rotated" alt="Running" height="128px" width="128px" src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/running_shoes/running_shoes_PNG5815.png" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>first line</p>
            <p>second line</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img alt="Others sports" height="128px" width="128px" src="https://storage.needpix.com/rsynced_images/bicycle-159680_1280.png"
          />
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>first line</p>
            <p>second line</p>
            <p>third line</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end card -->

        <!-- card -->
        <div class="card m-3">
          <img alt="Music" height="128px" width="128px" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/29/17/47/battery-4803149_960_720.png" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>first line</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end card -->

    </div>
    <!-- end cards container -->
  </div>

  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- javascript -->
</body>

</html>
```

Please tell me about any problem about this question.

Thanks for any idea about this !

EDIT: I discovered that everything work fine if the top property value is in "px", but it doesn't work if the top attribute have a value in "%". I veryfy parent and closure tags " to know  if the image wasn't in a smaller parent than others but it's not the case ...

RE-EDIT: I found where the problem come but not the solution ... On my example, every cards have a different text. And then not the same content height.
On my code, the bike card have the higher content height, and after delete it, the shoe card have the hier text content.

On the exemple I put here, the shoe card have the higher text-content (three lines) the shoe card have a different behaviour than others.

The card-deck layout give the same height to every cards, whatever their content. I'm pretty sure that it have a consequence on top property behavior.

Comment: It would be great if you could create a minimum reproducible example for this. Include the bare minimum HTML and CSS demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Hmm you think that put my code inside a <body> </body> tag isn't enough to reproduce it ? :/

Comment: Nope I mean your images here won't load because you've pasted code directly from whatever templating engine you're using. If you'd add placeholder images and only the least amount of HTML and CSS required, it would help debug the problem.

Comment: Oh ok got it, I just edited my post

Comment: the code you posted does not reproduce the issue you describe, please check it

Comment: Edited. The html had an div less than the original ... I also put a full html page with bootstrap. This page will be enough to reproduce the problem if you replace the css file in head tag by the css given in the question. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use flex then you could do the following to all of your cards:

```
<div class="card m-3 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">

    <img alt="Music" height="128px" width="128px" src="{{ asset("images/curriculum_vitae/hobbies/drum_set.png") }}"/>

    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Musique</h5>
        <p>[...]</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

I've added 4 [bootstrap helper classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) to your card's class list. If you want to check whether the browsers you're targeting support flex, [you can read here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

If you're unsure on how flex works you can read about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

Comment: Hello and thank you foryour help !
It worked half, the fact is that if i remove my top and left css attributes, every images have the same behaviour. The problem is that I have a hover effect, that bring the hovered mage to the top of the card. But even with your solution, the third card image don't move to the top because it's not affected by the top property.

So thank you to your answer, but if you know why the third card image isn't affected by the top property it can be usefull.

Comment: EDIT: I discovered that everything work fine if the top property value is in "px", but it doesn't work if the top attribute have a value in "%". I veryfy parent and closure tags "</div> to know  if the image wasn't in a smaller parent than others but it's not the case ...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: This isn't a fancy way to do it, but at least it solve the problem...

I'm calling this lines of codes on pages loaded and on page resized:

```
$(".card").each(function() {
    $(this).css("height", $(this).height() + "px");
});
```

This code give to each cards it's own hight ... But in px. Wich, for a reason I can't explain solve the problem if the card have a CSS constant height in px.

For peoples that don't know, jQuery should be added to make this code work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, that you know what outerHeight() is: https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/ If your containers get more fatter, maybe you need this instead of .height(). There is also innerHeight. Also, let it be noted, that such animations do not generally require jquery to work. That is just an extra rendering delay.